# SSH connection permission denied

Tags: ssh

I am trying to login into remote server without password using ssh but I am get the error:

```
Permission denied (public key)
```

To copy `.pub` key to the server, I had:

```
PasswordAuthentication = yes (in the sshd_config file).
```

After I copied the `.pub` key, the i disabled the password in the `ssh_config` I had:

```
PasswordAuthentication = no
```

Now when I tried to ssh:

```
ssh 'server@192.168.xx.x'
```

I was getting the error:

```
Permission denied (public key)
```

How can I solve the problem?

I have changed the authorized_keys permission, the `.ssh/` permission and so on, but the problem persist. I have even used the `ssh-agent $SHELL && ssh-add` command.

Comment: Don't describe what you did, describe what you have. Show permissions of the files of the server, show the commands you used to copy files. Was the pub key in the correct format? Run `ssh -vvv` to show verbose output. Show errors from the ssh server logs.

Comment: You need to check the ssh logs on the server (e.g. `/var/log/auth.log` on Debian, `/var/log/secure` on Red Hat). You also should not have disabled password authentication until you were sure that the public key authentication worked.

Answer (score 1):

I always use below step to create new ssh connection to remote machines:

1. Generate a new `ssh` key pair (just press enter until back to shell):

   ```
   localhost$ (cd .ssh && ssh-keygen -t rsa -f id_rsa_2)
   localhost$ cp .ssh/id_rsa_2.pub .ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
2. Copying the newly created public key to remote machine:

   ```
   localhost$ (cd .ssh && ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa_2 username@myIP)
   username@myIP password:
   ```
3. Now try to login (there will be no password prompt):

   ```
   ssh username@myIP
   ```

> Notes:  I never edit `ssh_config` and `sshd_config` so maybe you can
>   restore them back to the original state unless they already connected.

Comment: Your second line in step 1 is useless and overwrites all previously stored public keys on that machine.

Comment: yes you are right. I have edit the command. It should good now.

Answer (score 1):

When you see this error:

> Permission denied (public key)

It means there is a problem with the key you are using. **It doesn't necessarily mean that you are using an invalid key.** The problem can also be a the the server has trouble verifying your key.

Often times, wrong ownership or permissions on the `.ssh` folder or `authorized_keys` file is the reason for a valid key not te be accepted. Check the following:

- Is the `/home/<user>/.ssh` folder owned by `<user>`?
- Does the folder have permissions for the user only (chmod 0700)?
- Is the `/home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys` file owned by `<user>`?
- Does the `/home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys` file have permissions for `<user>` only (chmod 0600)?

The following commands should ensure that (when run as the specific user):

```
chown -R $USER ~/.ssh
chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

If that still does not help, also check the log files for further clues as to what might be wrong. Enabling verbose logging on the SSH client can also lead to useful clues, just:

```
ssh <IP> -l <user> -vvv
```

To get more detailed output what SSH is doing/trying.